# Troubles with my navBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

i have a navigation Bar Item. When the app loads, i have this code so the navbar has the height that i want...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let height: CGFloat = 38
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
}
```

The problem is that when i press the homeButton and then i return to the app, the navbar changes the height, and i want the height to be like the first time you run the app

It seems like when i first run the app, the height of the navbar takes the value that i want, but then, when i close and reopen the app, it takes the original value (the default height value of the navbar).

What should i do? Should i implement another method?? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use autolayout constraint properly in your storyboard file. And then you do not have to set the height programmatically. But if you would like to manipulate programmatically then move your code in `ViewDidload` instead of `ViewDidAppear` method.

```
let height: CGFloat = 38
let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried... But when i close the app and reopen it, the height of the navbar is different from the first time. I don't now why this is happening

Comment: Close you mean after quit the app?

Comment: Yeah. Not quit at all, it happen when i press the homeButton, so the app is still working in a second plane

Comment: Ok, then in that case you just need to set the height CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: height) remove bounds.height.

Comment: Otherwise bounds.height will update your height everytime you appear the screen

Comment: Where should i put that code??? I tried putting that in the viewdidload, but it didn't work

Comment: Did you remove bounds.height??

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work. It seems like when i first run the app, the height of the navbar takes the value that i want, but then, when i close and reopen the app, it takes the original value (the default height value of the navbar).

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard select your  `Navaigation Item > Prompt Field` add space to increase the height of Navigation bar

And have your code in either viewDidAppear(As you have today) or viewWillAppear

Comment: The thing is that i don't have storyboard

Comment: Here you go: self.navigationItem.prompt = "    "

Comment: Yeah, it works. So i tried to put that and i deleted my code, and now the navbar gets a bigger height than the default one. But, how can i change the height???

Comment: The way you expand same way you have to reduce i.e by changing the prompt value you no space(ideally blank and no white space value )self.navigationItem.prompt = " "

Comment: I tried putting that in viewdidappear method, but the navbar is smaller than i expect. If i put that in the viewdidload instead, the navbar is more bigger than i expect. What do you think should do???

Comment: It should go in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear as viewDidLoad is called just first time and once its in memory it will not called again like viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods are not designed to work like that. If your application goes to inactive and become active again while a UIViewController on the foreground it won't call any of those methods.

You can track that from `applicationDidBecomeActive` method in `AppDelegate`.

But if you want to know that in a specific view controller you can use the notification named `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should subclass the UINavigationController, but keep the navigationbar it self is the best, if you wat to add something on the bar, you can add a uitoolbar on the ViewController's view, and toolBar.frame = (0,64,screenWidth, 30), then delete the hair line of navigationbar , and it will look like the navigationbar been extended